Can I run a systemd service on foreground for testing?
I want something like systemctl start-in-foreground logstash, so that I can see the output on the terminal and able to  ctrl-c it. But I still want systemd to run the process with the right User= and Group=, EnvironmentFile=, etc.

Not in the foreground,  but would running jounrnalctl -u logstash -follow in a separate terminal give you the necessary information?

This is what I do now, I was after a quick way to test in a way that I crtl-c and I that stops both the text output and the service. Now I have to systemctl restart all the time and its annoying hence the question.

Yes and no, mostly no.
Regular .services cannot be run in foreground. There is a systemd-run tool which creates temporary services with the specified parameters and has the ability to connect the service's stdin/stdout either through a pipe or a pty, but it cannot automatically import an existing .service definition – you have to manually list every parameter in command line:
systemd-run --pipe --collect --uid=foo -o EnvironmentFile=foo /usr/bin/logstash --foo

